# How to resolved this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'clinical1'?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
import keras.backend as K
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
import pandas as pd
class CustomThreshold(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    """ Custom threshold wrapper for binary classification"""
    def __init__(self, base, threshold=0.5):
        self.base = base
        self.threshold = threshold
    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.base.fit(*args, **kwargs)
        return self
    def predict(self, X):
        return (self.base.predict_proba(X)[:, 1] > self.threshold).astype(int)

dataset_clinical = np.loadtxt("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/BreastCancer-master/Data/stacked_metadata.csv",delimiter=",")
X = dataset_clinical[:,0:450]
Y = dataset_clinical[:,450]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=1)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10).fit(X,Y)
#rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)  
clf = [CustomThreshold(rf, threshold) for threshold in [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]]

for model in clf:
    print(confusion_matrix(y_test, model.predict(X_test)))
for model in clf:
    print(confusion_matrix(Y, model.predict(X)))

#print(confusion_matrix(Y, clf.predict(X)))
#assert((clf[1].predict(X_test) == clf[1].base.predict(X_test)).all())
#assert(sum(clf[0].predict(X_test)) > sum(clf[0].base.predict(X_test)))
#assert(sum(clf[2].predict(X_test)) < sum(clf[2].base.predict(X_test)
```

This is the traceback error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RF.py", line 24, in <module>
    dataset_clinical = np.loadtxt("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/BreastCancer-master/Data/stacked_metadata.csv",delimiter=",")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1139, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1067, in read_data
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1067, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 763, in floatconv
    return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'clinical1'
```

Comment: Could you please put the Traceback Error Message in a separate field (by putting it on a new line and adding ">" to the beginning. Thanks :)

Comment: As a default `loadtxt` tries to load everything as floats, numbers.  Your file has strings that don't qualify, such as the "clinical1".  Only **you** know what's in the file, so it's up to you locate the problem.  It does look like that header, but that's just a guess.  You may need to take some time and read `loadtxt` docs.  Actually you should have done that **first**.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
numpy.loadtxt(fname, dtype='float', comments='#', delimiter=None, converters=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None, unpack=False, ndmin=0)
```

If your file has text information, such as column headers for example, then when you read the file and it expects information of type float, this could cause the problem you are seeing.

**Parameters:**

> `fname`: File, filename, or generator to read. If the filename extension is .gz or .bz2, the file is first decompressed. Note that generators should return byte strings for Python 3k.
>
> `dtype`: Data-type of the resulting array; default: float. If this is a structured data-type, the resulting array will be 1-dimensional, and each row will be interpreted as an element of the array.
>
> `delimiter`: The string used to separate values. By default, this is any whitespace.
>
> `converters`: A dictionary mapping column number to a function that will convert that column to a float. E.g., if column 0 is a date string: converters = {0: datestr2num}. Default: None.
>
> `skiprows`: Skip the first skiprows lines; default: 0.
>
> **Returns**: ndarray

So you may be able to pass the optional arg `skiprows` if this is the case..